# Docusign CreateConsoleview returnurl not working

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am having issue with docusign CreateConsoleView returnurl method. CreateConsoleView method gives me view url that is used by user to see their signature, but when user clicks close button after verify their signature, docusign redirecting the user to docusign console page instead of redirecting to given return url. Is it known bug or am i missing something?

```
        ConsoleViewRequest consoleViewRequest = new ConsoleViewRequest();
        consoleViewRequest.EnvelopeId = "77cd8ac2-d69e-4c4a-9968-46ffa2a56331";
        consoleViewRequest.ReturnUrl = "https://www.google.com";

        ViewUrl viewUrl = envelopesApi.CreateConsoleView(accountId, consoleViewRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ReturnUrlRequest urlRequest = new ReturnUrlRequest();
urlRequest.EnvelopeId = "77cd8ac2-d69e-4c4a-9968-46ffa2a56331";
urlRequest.ReturnUrl = "https://www.google.com";

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
ViewUrl viewUrl = envelopesApi.CreateConsoleView(accountId, urlRequest);
```

Comment: I tried to use that one but ReturnUrlRequest doesnt have EnvelopeId.

Comment: Also, CreateConsoleView does not accept ReturnUrlRequest and it only accept ConsoleViewRequest.

Comment: Please  refer  below link.
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/open-the-docusign-console-from-your-app

Comment: I already went through that page and the example code is not useful. They creating ReturnurlRequest but not passing to CreateConsoleView method. In that example there is no envelope id is passed and it will redirect the user to docusign console page

Comment: I m now  sure but try this https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/ConsoleViewRequest/-/php-consoleviewrequest-class-examples.html

Comment: Tried it. Did not work. They are creating ReturnUrlRequest but they are not passing that instance to any method.